# Product list pagination not working correctly for category with over 50 products

Tags: product-list, pagination, category-listing, list

I have a multistore with 4 stores. Three of the 4 are working correctly as they have under 50 products in the specific category. The one with more than 50, shows next page after the final product, and on the next page an error "We can't find any stores" (*stores have been created as products*). I have checked the admin settings for list view and everything looks correct. We have also checked custom theme code and there are no limits set. Using Magento ver. 2.3.5-p2.